# Shadow problem Floating Action Button (api = 19)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, floating-action-button

I had a problem with FAB shadow on API <= 19. I used compatElevation= 0f and shadow disappeared. But it appears again during onClick and looks strange:

[image]

XML code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/RateBtn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/backet_Btn_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/backet_Btn_size"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"


    android:src="@drawable/star_rate2"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/w"


    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/langBtn2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/langBtn2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/SettingsBtn"

    app:rippleColor="@color/grey_700" />
```

Code:

```
var fb = view?.findViewById(R.id.RateBtn) as FloatingActionButton
val lp =it.layoutParams

            if (lp !=null){
                lp.width= size_fb
                lp.height=size_fb
                it.customSize=size_fb
                it.layoutParams= lp
            }
```

I think there is some problem when I try to change FAB size programmatically. When I set size in xml, everything is ok

Comment: share your code what you have tried?

Comment: share the XML code of your FloatingActionButton please.

Comment: Ok, I shared code in the question

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
android:elevation="0dp" 
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried id and it's ok until you press the button. During clicking you get this thing as I showed in question (square with rounded corners)

Answer (score 0):

Override the default elevation of the FAB by adding

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried id and it's ok until you press the button. During clicking you get this thing as I showed in question (square with rounded corners)

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
setStateListAnimator(null);
```

XML

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Comment: Call requires API Level 21

Comment: I updated Android Studio and the error disappeared.

build.gradle looks exactly the same:

Comment: I think there is some problem when I try to change FAB size programmatically. When I set size in xml, everything is ok